# JavaMail POP3 mail client error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am working on a java mail client:

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MailClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            Session session;

            URLName url = new URLName("pop3","pop.gmail.com",995,"","email@gmail.com","password");
            session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session,url);
            store.connect();

            Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            Message message[] = folder.getMessages();

            for (int i=0, n = message.length; i<n; i++) {
                System.out.println(message[i].getSubject());
            }
            folder.close(false);
            store.close();
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

The error that is occurring is this:

```
MailClient.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session,url);
symbol: class POP3SSLStore
location: class MailClient
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an import:

```
import com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore;
```

After that it should compile

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be instantiating the Store object yourself.  Let the Session do it for you.  Call session.getStore("pop3s").  See the example code included with the [JavaMail download bundle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html), and the examples in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html), especially the [Gmail example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).